# Template that matches the first occurrence of a specific element in an XML document

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML document with a structure similar to the following:

```
<article>
   <header>
      <metadata>
          bunch of metadata nodes here
          <abstract>
              <p>this is one of the abstract's paragraphs</p>
          </abstract>
      </metadata>
   </header>
   <body>
      <sec>
         <title>This is title 1</title>
         <p>Paragraph 1</p>
         <p>paragraph 2</p>
         <title>This is title 2</title>
      <sec>
         <title>This is title 3</title>
         <p>paragraph 1 under title 3</p>
         <p>paragraph 2 under title 3</p>
   </body>
 </article>
```

The real XML can certainly get a lot more complex that the above, but it should suffice to illustrate.

I need to apply a specific template only to the first `<p>` element occurring inside the `<body>` element. I can easily write an xpath expresion that selects for the the node I am interested in:

```
(//body//p)[1]
```

Unfortunately this xpath expression can not be used as the match expression in an XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="(//body//p)[1]">
<p_first>
    <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
</p_first>
</xsl:template>
```

The template above will throw an error when trying to run it through the XSL engine. Is there a match expression that I can use to select the element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to use something like

```
<xsl:template match="body//p[count(preceding::p) = count(ancestor::body/preceding::p)]">
```

i.e. to find a `p` inside the body for which the number of other `p` elements ahead of *it* is the same as the number ahead of the opening `<body>` tag.

Alternatively

```
<xsl:template match="body//p[not(preceding::p[ancestor::body])]">
```

would look for a `p` that does not have any predecessor `p` elements that are themselves descendants of the `body`.  The `ancestor::body` constraint is necessary because *every* `body//p` is preceded by the `p` that is inside the `abstract`.  It would get more complicated still if there could be more than one `body` element, since we're only checking for `p`s that are inside *a* `body` element, not necessarily *the same* `body`.

Comment: It works .. I am still trying to understand the expression though ... I was hoping something of the sort of match="body//p[not(preceding::body//p)]" could work but it obviously does not.

Comment: good .. now I understand the logic behind the expression but was wondering is there is an easier way to check if there are any preceding <p> elements under <body>

Comment: @osantos `count(preceding::p)` is the total number of `p` elements before the one we're currently testing, which will vary depending on which `p` we're looking at now.  `count(//body/preceding::p)` is the number of `p` elements before the `body`, which will always be the same (1, in this example).  The `p` you're interested in is the one where these two numbers match.

Comment: @osantos I've added an alternative pattern you could try which you might consider slightly clearer.

Comment: Thanks .. I like this second approach much better.  Thank you all for your help. Fortunately there is only one body element in each xml document I am dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

Try `match="body//p[not(preceding::p)]"`.

Comment: Tried it but no node seems to be matching this expression. I also tried the expression in eclipse's xpath expression as //body//p[not(preceding::p)] and nothing was matched.

Comment: Depends on the other templates you have. How about `match="//p[not(preceding::p)]"`?

Comment: Also, since there is a <p> element inside the <abstract> element, then the first <p> element inside the body does not match the expression. Therefore nothing really matches the expression as stated. Somehow I should be able to extend this expression to say that there are no preceding <p> elements INSIDE the <body> element.